# bitwise shifting in reverse in javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, decoding

I am wondering how I can make the following bit shifting process in reverse?

```
chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));
chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);
chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);
```

This is basically shifting the bits for a decoding script Im using. Im wondering is there a way to reverse this process, for encoding instead of decoding?

This comes from the following script which decodes in base64:

```
Base64 = {
        _keyStr: ".ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+=",
        decode: function( input ) {
                    var output = "";
                    var hex = "";
                    var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
                    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
                    var i = 0;
                    var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\.\=]/g;

                    do {
                        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;

                        chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));                                                                                                             
                        chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);                                                                                                     
                        chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);


                        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
                        if (enc3 != 64) {
                            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                        }
                        if (enc4 != 64) {
                            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                        }
                        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
                    } while (i < input.length);

                    return (output);
                }
}
```

Comment: looks to me like there is information loss in moving from enc1234 to chr123... if so it can't be reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe the following calculations:

```
// enc = [0, 1, 0, 0]
chr1 = (0 | ((1 & 3) << 6)) = 64
chr2 = (1 >> 2) | ((0 & 0x0F) << 4) = 0
chr3 = (0 >> 4) | (0 << 2) = 0

// enc = [64, 0, 0, 0]
chr1 = (64 | ((0 & 3) << 6)) = 64
chr2 = (0 >> 2) | ((0 & 0x0F) << 4) = 0
chr3 = (0 >> 4) | (0 << 2) = 0
```

Since two inputs map to the same outputs, the function is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), i.e. cannot be reversed.

If you assume that all values of enc are <64, you can reverse it though:

```
enc1 = chr1 & 0x3f;
enc2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0xf) << 2);
enc3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 4);
enc4 = chr3 >> 2;
```

Since the space of values isn't that large, you can simply test them all out, right here in your browser:

```js
'use strict';

function _indicate(status) {
  var indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator');
  while (indicator.firstChild) {
    indicator.removeNode(firstChild);
  }
  indicator.setAttribute('class', status);
  indicator.appendChild(document.createTextNode(status));
}

function test(enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4) {
  var chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));
  var chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);
  var chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);

  var dec1 = chr1 & 0x3f;
  var dec2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0xf) << 2);
  var dec3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 4);
  var dec4 = chr3 >> 2;

  if ((enc1 !== dec1) || (enc2 !== dec2) || (enc3 !== dec3) || (enc4 !== dec4)) {
    console.log('FAIL');
    console.log('chr ' + chr1 + ', ' + chr2 + ', ' + chr3);
    console.log('Expected/got: ' + enc1 + '/' + dec1 + ', ' + enc2 + '/' + dec2 + ', ' + enc3 + '/' + dec3 + ', ' + enc4 + '/' + dec4);
    _indicate('fail');
    throw new Error('Failed test');
  }
}


for (var enc1 = 0; enc1 < 63; enc1++) {
  for (var enc2 = 0; enc2 < 63; enc2++) {
    for (var enc3 = 0; enc3 < 63; enc3++) {
      for (var enc4 = 0; enc4 < 63; enc4++) {
        test(enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4);
      }
    }
  }
}
_indicate('pass');
```

```css
.fail {
  background: red;
}
.pass {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="indicator"></div>
```

Comment: Hi phihag, I've added the rest of the script to my question. Is it really not possible to create an encoding function, using the same bitwise shifting? It's just that I have seen many functions like this in the past and they always have a reverse (encoding) function, so my guess is that it is possible for this script. In this case, I don't have it and am trying to recreate on my own.

Comment: No, the above is a mathematical proof that it is **not possible** to write an encoding function if the encoding operates on arbitrary integers. However, you're in luck - your encoding just maps from [0, 64[ to [0, 255[, and therefore is reversible. I have added code that does that.

Comment: `enc1 = chr1 && 0x3f;` is that the logical and? Does this mean `enc1` can only be `1` or `0`?

Comment: Hi phihag, thanks very much, however I cant seem to test whether it works. I've created another question about this where Ive given a test example. It's very close, but there is some bit shifting problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048873/base64-encoding-in-javascript-with-bit-shifting

Comment: @Ke. I added code to a test that proves the transformation to be correct. I apologize for the error in a previous version - the bitmask for enc1 should be `0xf`.

Comment: This is seriously clever stuff phihag. I sincerely thank you for your help in understanding this.