# base64 encoding in javascript with bit shifting

Tags: javascript, base64, decode, encode, arraybuffer

I have the following decode/encode routine. However, the encoding is not working properly (it should be printing "CMlaKA" not "ClaKA" to the console log). I think the problem is with the bit shifting, but I cant tell where.

Here is a jsfiddle to explain

https://jsfiddle.net/4yfrLv9y/16/

Here is the code (routine is run at the bottom)

```
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};

var Base64 = {
        _keyStr: ".ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+=",

    encode : function (input) {
        var output = [],
            chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4,
            i = 0;
        while (i < input.length) {
            chr1 = input[i++];
            chr2 = input[i++];
            chr3 = input[i++];

            enc1 = chr1 & 0x3f;
            enc2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0x3c) << 2);
            enc3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 4);
            enc4 = chr3 >> 2;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output.push([this._keyStr.charAt(enc1),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc2),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc3),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc4)].join(''));
        }

        return output.join('');
    },

    decodeAsArray: function (b) {
        var d = this.decode(b),
            a = [],
            c;
                //alert("decoded base64:" + d);
        for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++) {
            a[c] = d.charCodeAt(c)
        }
                //alert("returning a");
        return a
    },

    decode: function( input ) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;

            chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));
            chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);
            chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                        }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return (output);
    }

};

basedecode();

function basedecode(){
//Converts 'CMlaKa to CcnK by base64'
    var decoded = "CMlaKA"
    //67 99 110 75 0 0  - This is the Byte Array, or ArrayBuffer of CcnK
    decoded = Base64.decode(decoded)
    console.log(decoded);
}

baseencode();

function baseencode(){
    var encoded = [67,99,110,75];// byte array of CcnK
    console.log(Base64.encode(encoded) + ' ---- Should be CMlaKA not ClaKA== - why is it different?'); 
}
```

Comment: Unless you're supporting lower than IE10, why rewrite base64 functions when they already exist in the browser? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64

Comment: I'm not using JS in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't found your implementation algorithm, but found this one in [wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64)
 and corrected yours

```
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};

var Base64 = {
        _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",

    encode : function (input) {
        var output = [],
            chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4,
            i = 0;
        while (i < input.length) {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i+1);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i+2);
            i+=3;

                        /* enc1 = chr1 && 0x3f;
                        enc2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0x3c) << 4);
                        enc3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 2);
                        enc4 = chr3 >> 2; */

            var _24c = (chr1 << 16) + (chr2 << 8) + chr3;
            //n = [(n >>> 18) & 63, (n >>> 12) & 63, (n >>> 6) & 63, n & 63];
            enc1 = _24c >>> 18 & 63
            enc2 = _24c >>> 12 & 63
            enc3 = _24c >>> 6 & 63
            enc4 = _24c & 63


           /**  if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }
             */
            output.push([this._keyStr.charAt(enc1),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc2),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc3),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc4)].join(''));
        }

        return output.join('');
    },

    decodeAsArray: function (b) {
        var d = this.decode(b),
            a = [],
            c;
                //alert("decoded base64:" + d);
        for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++) {
            a[c] = d.charCodeAt(c)
        }
                //alert("returning a");
        return a
    },

    decode: function( input ) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;

            chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));
            chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);
            chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                        }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return (output);
    }

};

// basedecode();

function basedecode(){
//Converts 'CMlaKa to CcnK by base64'
    var decoded = "CMlaKA"
    //67 99 110 75 0 0  - This is the Byte Array, or ArrayBuffer of CcnK
    decoded = Base64.decode(decoded)
    console.log(decoded);
}

// baseencode();

function baseencode(){
    var encoded = [67,99,110,75];// byte array of CcnK
    console.log(Base64.encode(encoded) + ' ---- Should be CMlaKA not +la+A== - where do the + and = signs come from?'); 
}

function hashAndAssert(string_to_hash, result) {
    var hash = Base64.encode(string_to_hash);
  return '' + (hash == result) + ', expected: ' + result + '; output: ' + hash;
}

function unitTest() {
    console.log('#1 Passed ' + hashAndAssert('', ''))
  console.log('#2 Passed ' + hashAndAssert('foo', 'Zm9v'))
  console.log('#1 Passed ' + hashAndAssert('foobar', 'Zm9vYmFy'))
}

unitTest();
```

Comment: `_24c` is a `24bit` char from 3 `8bit` chars.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't the solution Im looking for. The final result should be "CMlaKA" The reason for this is becasue of the bit shifting that is happening. My version is very close "ClaKA", but it's still not quite right. If you move the bit shifting around (as you have done in your answer), the base64 encoding will come out completely different, when it needs to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code and they involve not only the encode method, but the decode one as well.

First of all, you are using a bad key string. Accoring to Wikipedia [Wikipedia - Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) 'A' equals '0', not '.' as in your example.

**This will prevent you from checking your code against public websites for validity.**

This is the "standard" key string:

```
_keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
```

**The '=' in the end is for padding and should not be used directly during conversion**

Then, you got a problem with your byte shifting code.
You calculate the base64 values in the wrong direction. You should look at the Wikipedia link to see which bytes should be considered as each base64 value.

Here is a fixed snippet for the decoder:

```
chr1 = enc1 << 2 | ((enc2 & 0xc0) >> 6);
chr2 = ((enc2 & 0x0f) << 4) | ((enc3 & 0x3c) >> 2);
chr3 = ((enc3 & 0x03) << 6) | enc4;
```

Here is a fixed snippet for the encoder:

```
enc1 =  (chr1 & 0xfc) >> 2;
enc2 = ((chr1 & 0x03) << 4) | ((chr2 & 0xf0) >> 4);
enc3 = ((chr2 & 0x0f) << 2) | ((chr3 & 0xc0) >> 6);
enc4 =   chr3 & 0x3f;
```

Moreover, you must trim the output values (in the encoder) because they are in unlimited containers, so:

```
enc1 = enc1 & 0x3f;
enc2 = enc2 & 0x3f;
enc3 = enc3 & 0x3f;
```

Assuming you made all these changes, if the input to the decoder is "CMlaKA", the output is [12,217,155,44,16] and then the encoder will return the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, they key string (my understanding of it) is where you can put a password to encrypt the base64 with your own key. In the case above, there is just an extra dot, which doesnt matter really. The encoding/decoding should be the same.

Comment: @Ke. `Base64` **is not** encrypting. It's just converting binary data, to *safe* ASCII text

Comment: Just like @GRiMe2D said, base64 encryption is a bad idea! Moreover, the '.' is significant if you try to compare the values to a "standard" decoder/encoder for verification, as the indices of standard values, such as the letter 'A' are shifted.

Comment: The dot is needed to be able to decode base64 correctly in my case. It's not relevant to the question and doesnt matter what is included in the _keyStr variable. The encoding and decoding will still not come out the same if the bit shifting is not correct. That is the problem Im trying to overcome, and the edits given here don't get to the "CMlaKA" output that is needed.

Comment: Sadly enough, I can't help you if you can't explain why the result should be "CMlaKA". There might be other mistakes along the way which I can't verify.  The shifting methods I present here are correct in comparison to the website [base64encode.org](https://www.base64encode.org/)

Comment: This is explained in the decode function provided in the jsfiddle and in the question. The decode function decodes the base64 "CMlaKA" to "CcnK" - which is correct. I'm trying to get the encode function to do this backwards, so it will convert "CcnK" to "CMlaKA". I am very close, just missing the "M" so I think there is a problem in my bitwise operators, where it is shifting to far or something.

Comment: I've added the trimming as you suggested, which has resulted in an additional "A" in the base64 result as you can see here - https://jsfiddle.net/4yfrLv9y/18/  Unfortunately the "A" should be "M" so still looking for a solution to the bit shifting :/

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the decoding as well and now everything works.